# jmeter - how to extract a particular json value which is in base64 format

Tags: jmeter

I in a situation to exact a json value from a base64 encoded data.
i have used bean shell post processor to decode  and i got the decoded value.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
vars.put("decoded_response", new String(Base64.decodeBase64("eyJsdCI6ICJUa246ODY3MzYxYTgtY2FlZi00YzkxLTgwNjQtYTczMWUyNTg4N2VkIn0=")));
```

this is giving value like

```
decoded_response={"lt": "Tkn:867361a8-caef-4c91-8064-a731e25887ed"}
```

from this how can i extract **lt** value?

can some one help he?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) you will be able to extract it like:

```
encoded_response = 'eyJsdCI6ICJUa246ODY3MzYxYTgtY2FlZi00YzkxLTgwNjQtYTczMWUyNTg4N2VkIn0='

decoded_response = new String(encoded_response.decodeBase64())

lt = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(decoded_response).lt

log.info('lt value: ' + lt)
```

[image]

Reconsider using Beanshell as it's [some form of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) while Groovy:

- works faster
- provides Base64 encoding and decoding functions out of the box
- provides JSON parsing and building functions out of the box

More information:

- [EncodingGroovyMethods](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/EncodingGroovyMethods.html)
- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)